# How to pass image captured with camera to second view controller? Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an iOS camera app. Once an image is captured I would like to pass that image and display it in the next view controller. I am passing the image using the "prepare" function and when I pass an image not captured with my camera this works fine. However when I try to pass image captured I get this error:

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value at the line "nextView?.imageCaptured = self.capturedImage!"

Any ideas as to how to correctly do this?

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        // Make sure we get some photo sample buffer
        guard error == nil else{
            print("Error capturing photo: \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
        
        guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else {
            print("Fail to convert pixel buffer")
            return
        }
        
        // Initialise an UIImage with our image data
        self.capturedImage = UIImage.init(data: imageData , scale: 1.0)
        
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showResult", sender: capturedImage)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        if segue.identifier == "showResult" {
            let nextView = segue.destination as? ScanViewController
            nextView?.imageCaptured = self.capturedImage!
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possible problems.

The first and most likely lies in the `photoOutput` method. `UIImage(data: scale:)` is a failable initialiser, and for some reason it is failing to create the image you expect in

```
        self.capturedImage = UIImage.init(data: imageData , scale: 1.0)
```

and therefore `capturedImage` is nil, which result in the error when you try to force unwrap it.   You could guard against this by conditionally unwrapping it (which is a better defensive pattern generally):

```
if segue.identifier == "showResult" {
    if let nextView = segue.destination as? ScanViewController
        nextView?.imageCaptured = self.capturedImage!
    } else {
        // handle the error
    }
```

You could also test this by putting a breakpoint on it and seeing what the property is after stepping over the line.

The second possibility is just that the `photoOutput` method isn't being executed prior to segueing.  This seems unlikely but without a wider view of the code it's not possible to completely discount it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely implement a safer unwrapping. the image is initialized correctly since when i debugPrint capturedImage I get <UIImage:0x280f50360 anonymous {2376, 4224}> in the photoOutput method and Optional(<UIImage:0x280f50360 anonymous {2376, 4224}>) in the prepare method

Comment: That strange.  Are you sure the error if referring to that line, as that says the image is nil when it tries to unwrap it?  The only other way i can see for image being nil is if there's a variable scope or threading/sequencing issue.